# Sandhyavandanam during Asoucha period

Tags: sandhyavandanam

Can I do Sandhyavanadanam when Ladies in my home are under menstrual cycle ? Because of some unavoidable circumstances, Ladies can not sit separately during their period time.

I do 3 times Sandhyavandanam daily with lot of interest. But during Ladies period time, I am not doing that for 4 days thinking that it is not good to do Sandhyavandam during that time.

Can someone please advise on this? Is it correct that I am doing ? Somewhere I heard that we can do Sandhyavandanam during Asoucha perod also, but till Arghya Pradanam only, reciting silently. How far is it correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You must be having a different puja room right?The lady on courses shud not enter that room that's all.

Comment: I am very happy to know that you perform Sandhyavandanam daily 3 times. The information regarding performance of Sandhyavandana in Ashoucha is correct. Regarding females in their cycle period, you must avoid any physical contact with them if you don't want to take bath. If possible you should seperate their room or restrict their access to the places like Kitchen and Temple. You should cook for her and you should give water(rembember Avoid physical contact). Do not consume food cooked by that woman. If physical contact is unavoidable you should take bath before Sandhyavandanam.

Comment: Good to  note that u r doing 3 times sandhyavandanam. How you are doing Madyahnigam? Sandhyavandhna is nithya karma anushtana which should not be left. If you have terrace or side passage  in your house please perform there. Ensure the ladies undergoing period should not come there. You can do the full sandhyavandanam by reciting silently Pranayamam and gayatri japam will be told silently any day. Only upasthnam will be said in a voice which can be heard by others. recite that too silently.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable advises. Luckyly I have got an opportunity to work from home since past 1 yr. So I am doing Sandhyavandhana 3 times a day in a timely manner. When I go to Office I do Madyanigan in the morning itself.

Comment: @Anil--Madyanigam what time u perform when you go to office--It shld be after 8/30 am. two and half hours after the sunrise. That is why I cannot do madyanigam.How many times gayatri japam u perform during sandyavandhan?

Comment: Nothing to do with ladies. Please do perform sandhyavandhana - it's awesome that you are doing tri-kala sandhyavandhana, not many of us do it! Go ahead and don't stop it for anything please!

Comment: Hi Partha, If I go to Office, I usually go around 11 AM. So I do Madyanigam between 9Am to 10AM. I do 108 times Gayatri Japam in the morning and 11 times during Madyanigam and Evening. I try to do more Japam during weekends.

Comment: @Anil Keep it up. Do not leave at any cost. See my profile for homams.

Comment: Women's menstrual cycle has nothing to do with your sandhyavandanam. You should not stop sandhyavandanam till arghyam only. You should complete it regardless of your family members are under menstrual cycle. You should not read it loudly at any time. It gives you results when you do it silently. To add, a brahmachari doesn't have the effect of Jata asoucham (when someone are born in the family) if he does tri kala and Agnihotram. These days, no one are doing agni hotra. But continue Tri kala. Other's body condition doesn't effect your puja.

Comment: Do not close this. This is unfair voting to close!

Comment: @AkshayS There's no problem of reverse direction of close voting if the newer question is seemed more useful and have quality answers.