# Performing Pooja, japa etc during wife's monthly period

Tags: rituals, worship, women, dharma-shastras, sandhyavandanam

My question is should the men in the household perform sandhyavandanam,, Pooja and japa when the woman in the family is during her monthly menstrual cycle. We do not have provision to spare the only woman from doing her household chores including cooking, cleaning utensils, entering kitchen etc. But we have a separate Pooja room which she will refrain from entering during the 4 day period. 
I am really confused whether to perform my rituals during her period or not. Hoping to get a valuable asset as per Dharma shastras. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Your question is already asked [Sandhyavandanam during Asoucha period](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15633/5212). Yes, you can and you should perform puja and other daily rituals even when women in your family are under monthly period.

Comment: even in olden days, if only 1 woman in house, the husband is expected to do (and did), household chores - mainly cooking.

Answer (score 3):

After Upanayana performing Sandhya three times a day is a Nitya Karma for a Dvija. So, a Dvija has to do that without fail everyday.

When the Asaucha period (birth or death related impurity) runs in the family, even on those days he has to perform Sandhya (but Mantras should not be chanted loudly during those days).

From Devi Bhagavatam Book 11, Chapter 3:

> Therefore the morning bath is essentially necessary. The sins that
>   arise from going to those who are not fit for such purposes, from
>   accepting gifts from impure persons or from the practice of any other
>   secret vices all are removed by the morning ablutions. Without this
>   bath, no acts bear any fruit. Therefore everyday, this morning bath is
>   very necessary. Taking the Kus'a grass in hand, one is to perform
>   one's bath and Sandhyâ. If for seven days, the morning ablutions are
>   not taken, **and if for three days, the Sandhyâs are not performed**,
>   if for twelve days, the daily Homas be not performed, **the Brâhmanas
>   become S’ûdras.**

So, he can not stop doing Sandhya for **three days** because by doing so he becomes a Sudra as the verse given says. So, one is allowed to do.

Comment: Thank you. I presume the same applies to Nitya Pooja and japa also.

Comment: @Suresh Yes it applies to **all** Nitya Karmas whether it's Puja or Japa. Nitya karma can not be abandoned in any situations.